# get the arrows pressed on date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have a date picker on my website and I am trying to get show a message when either arrow is pressed on the date picker itself. The left arrow of the date pick is as follows:

```
    <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
```

But when I use javascript like so,

```
    $('.ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').click(function(){
        alert('here');
    });
```

Nothing happens

am I going about this wrong? How can I fix this?

I fixed this by,

```
    $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').click(function(){
        alert('here');
    });
```

Now it only works for one click, the class after the click is

```
    <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all" data-handler="prev" data-event="click" title="Prev"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span></a>
```

how can I get it to work for all clicks on that class?

I have a calendar click check and it works for all clicks:

```
    $('#calendar').click(function(){
        console.log(new Date());
    }
```

but my arrow click only works once

Answer (score 0):

The reason your .click() function doesn't work is because the code is called before the selector you want exists in the DOM, so no handler can be applied.

use (document).on("click", "yourSelectorHere", function(){//do stuff}); on dynamically created/edited content.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your .click() assignment works only **once** is:

Your DatePicker content is being regenerated each time the arrows are clicked.  So when you assign the .click() behavior, it gets erased and rewritten when the new month is loaded.

For example, if you are viewing **March**, the previous arrow is set to load **February**.  When you click the *previous* button, the DatePicker content is reloaded to display February.  The new behavior of that button's onclick event is no longer to load February, it is dynamically reassigned to load January.  So the one-time button `.click()` assignment you wrote for March's button gets thrown away after the month changes to a different month.

The March previous button is essentially an entirely different button than the February previous button.

---

Assuming the DatePicker is only reassigning the `onclick` event for the button and isn't recreating the button from scratch entirely, doing the following should **add** to existing event listeners but will not overwrite them.  So your added `onclick` event 'may' stick when the DatePicker `onclick` event is overwritten. Hopefully the DatePicker is written in a way that leaves other `onclick` events intact.

instead of:

```
 $('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w').click(function(){
        alert('here');
    });
```

try:

```
var prev_button = document.querySelector('.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w');

prev_button.addEventListener('click',function(){
   alert('Here');
},false);
```